# When I drag and drop controls onto TabPage in designer, they snap back to original position

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When I drag  any or all of the controls in the red circle onto the white TabControl, they slide over to where I want, but when I drop (ie. let go of the mouse button), the controls slide right back to where they were.

I've closed and re-opened Visual Studio 2017 Pro.

WORKAROUND:  I can however use the cursor keys to slide the controls to where I want, and they stay.

This has happened on another laptop a year ago.
Windows 10 Pro.

APRIL 2020 UPDATE...
Okay, it's been a year and a half and Visual Studio still has this malfunction. Just started happening again today after at least a year of never happening.  I've only been merrily programming for several hours and I copy-and-pasted to make two copies of a checkbox, clicked-and-drag a checkbox and BOOM! it snaps back to where the drag began.  I'd been doing nothing else.   Present VS is 16.5.4

[image]

Comment: This should not happen. Can you re-create the effect?

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, this should not happen. Yes.

Comment: This is happening to me on VS2022 also.  And similarly, moving the button via cursor arrows serves as a work-a-round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKAROUND #2...

1. Drag new control from tab control to a different location on the form beyond the tab control.
2. Cut it
3. Paste it back to the tab control.
4. If still won't drag, then use cursor keys to move it.

WORKAROUND #3 (APRIL 2020)...

1. Closed all VS Docs
2. Closed VS
3. Re-opened and no more snaps.